# Incorrect result for date comparison (to a timestamp column) in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, where-clause

I've been having some 'strange' results while comparing dates.
`table1` has two rows with TIMESTAMPS values `2009-08-26 23:39:56` and `2009-08-27 00:01:42`
When I make this query:

```
select * from table1 c
INNER JOIN table2 r ON r.table1_id = c.id
WHERE DATE(c.authorization_date) = '2009-08-26'
```

it returns both rows (when it only should have returned one).

For added weirdness the rows in the returned resultSet have tha same value: `2009-08-26 23:39:56`

But If I make this query:

```
SELECT DATE(authorization_date) FROM table1
```

It correctly returns two rows with values `2009-08-26` and `2009-08-27`

So, here comes my questions. How could I make the comparison so the correct result is returned, what am i doing wrong? Could be related to the inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected:

- some timezone discrepency, but you seem to have accounted for that
- some other data that is confusing the problem... is there something else that could be interfering?

Wish I could recreate this and help. Here's my setup code. What am I missing?

```
mysql> create table table1 (id integer primary key auto_increment, authorization_date TIMESTAMP);
mysql> insert into table1 values (1, '2009-08-26 23:39:56');
mysql> insert into table1 values (2, '2009-08-27 00:01:42');
mysql> create table table2 (table1_id integer);
mysql> insert into table2 values (1);
mysql> insert into table2 values (2);


    mysql> SELECT DATE(authorization_date) FROM c;
    +--------------------------+
    | DATE(authorization_date) |
    +--------------------------+
    | 2009-08-26               | 
    | 2009-08-27               | 
    +--------------------------+

    mysql> select * from table1 c INNER JOIN table2 r ON r.table1_id = c.id WHERE DATE(c.authorization_date) = '2009-08-26';
    +----+---------------------+-----------+
    | id | authorization_date  | table1_id |
    +----+---------------------+-----------+
    |  1 | 2009-08-26 23:39:56 |         1 | 
    +----+---------------------+-----------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry, I put what i believe was enough info, but i couldn't be more wrong... This setup cause me no problems, but my original setup do.
I paste my original setup in hope you or anyone could tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: @ndp: Shame on me!!!, the problem was that table2 has a primary compound key
(I hate primary compound keys) so the inner join was getting two rows.
Sorry for making you waste your time and very thanks!